# Material UI error loading specific components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, components

I'm having errors when I do use some of mui library components like **`Buttons, Tooltip, Popover`** and some similar. The error message isn't giving me a good hint to understand what is going on. The browser console has the following:

> 1. **`Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`**

> 2. **`Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).shape is undefined`**

> 3. **`The above error occurred in the <MuiButtonRoot> component:`**

> 4. **`Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).shape is undefined`**

Here is the source where I using the specified components:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

export default function BasicTooltip() {
  return (
    <Tooltip title="Delete">
      <IconButton>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

and my `package.json` dependencies section:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.2",
    "@mui/joy": "^5.0.0-alpha.41",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

I don't know if there's some other components that produce the same error, or if there's some dependencies that I missed I need help please and thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and the thing that solved it for me was I forgot to input my mui theme object to the `createTheme` function. May or may not be the same issue for you or anyone else.

The key in the error message `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).shape is undefined` is the `.shape is undefined` because mui is looking for values which should be defined in the theme object and `shape` is one of the keys along with `palette`, `typography`, etc. The `createTheme` function fills in the rest of the theme values with [the defaults](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/)

e.g.

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { cyan, pink } from '@mui/material/colors';

const theme = {
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
    primary: {
      main: cyan['A200'],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: pink['A400'],
    },
  },
};

export const muiTheme = createTheme(theme);
```